# testing foreign keys with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm trying to set up the background for a cucumber Feature. Ideally I want to be able to do:

```
Given the following folders exist:
     | id | parent_id | name             |
     | 1  |  nil      | folder1          |   
     | 2  |  nil      | folder2          |   
     | 3  |  2        | folder3          |   
     | 4  |  1        | folder4          |   
     | 5  |  1        | folder5          |   
     | 6  |  5        | folder6          |
```

However I can't do this as I can't set the ID of a particular model and so the first row may be created with an ID of 7 and therefore none of the other "child" rows can access it. Name is not unique so I can't do a find_by_name in the step definition. I've got a feeling it's gonna be some ugly nested array solution. 
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up doing it in my step definitions:

```
Given /^the following folders exist:$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each{|f|
    folder = Folder.new(f)
    folder.save
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('UPDATE folders SET id = '+f['id'].to_s+' WHERE id = '+folder.id.to_s)
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you can't choose unique names for the purpose of your configuring the test?

Comment: This is not sufficient as I need to be able to cope with (and test) duplicate names.